# Flask on EC2 AWS

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, flask

I am trying to run my Flask Application using python 3.5 on EC2 AWS instance.
I have tried the same application on my system and it ran well using the link:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1.0/people/?email=jaffer@example.com
```

Similarly, I have launched the Flask app on AWS instance, but after hitting the url in the similar fashion, I could not see the output:
http://ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5000/api/v1.0/people/

I launched the application as:

```
 python3.5 FlaskRestAPI.py
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Kindly, let me know what I need to do to see the output?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the localhost interface. You'll need to bind it to an external IP, or 0.0.0.0.

Comment: @DanielRoseman How I can do that.. please can you share with me?

Comment: Don't know. What does FlaskRestAPI look like?

Comment: @DanielRoseman your idea works.. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need some sort of Webserver Gateway Interface like uWSGI or Gunicorn and most likely a web server/reverse proxy like Nginx or Apache.

Here is a nice tutorial that uses uWSGI and Nginx: http://bathompso.com/blog/Flask-AWS-Setup/

Comment: That's not required. You can run a public Flask server

Comment: How do you run a public flask server?

Answer (score 0):

One better way to do this would be to host your flask application on AWS using the ElasticBeanstalk service of AWS. It is a seamless process and it gets your flask application working in minutes. You also get a public URL through which you can access your flask application.

More detailed instructions available here on how to how a flask application on AWS using ElasticBeanstalk:

[Hosting a flask application using ElasticBeanstalk](https://github.com/kmrambo/Deploying-a-Flask-or-Dash-application-using-AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk)